# query in departments node firebase to get 5 items from each node android

Tags: android, firebase

Firebase contains some departments node and doctors node so I have a relationship between doctors and departments with key department id. Each doctor has department id so I want to show in my query 5 child from doctors for each department how can I use query firebase to get result 5 children for doctors for each department android.

how to do the query in android?

I tried to query the department first
and then in for each department id make a query to get some child of doctors 
but I think it will make my app slowly

Firebase node structure:

[image: Here]

Comment: Did my answer help you @m.senan ?

Comment: @PradyumanDixit hellow i need to get all department at the same time not one department . i need to fill expand listview  with departments and doctors in each department

Comment: do i need to change the structure of database ? @PradyumanDixit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from your question, you want to get list of 5 doctors who have a certain department Id.

You can do so using `orderByChild()` and `limitToLast()` and simple `singleValueEventListener()`. The code may look something like this:

```java
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Doctors");
                    ref.orderByChild("depid").equalTo(2).limitToFirst(5).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                              for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                   String name = dataSnapshot.child("name");
                                   // or do anything else
                              }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```

This code will get first 5 doctors' names in the variable `name` one by one who have `depid` as 2. You can edit it according to your future needs.

You can use different `depid` values to show different doctors from different departments in this.

Comment: hellow  @PradyumanDixit thanks for answering my question . I need to do the same query that you wrote for all department to fill one list of doctors  to show it in nested list view  your query just get one department in one time i need to get all department in one query to fill listview with department and doctors as expand listview

Comment: @m.senan you can duplicate this code with changing the values of `depid`, and you know this, that's good. But if you want to get all of the doctors from all of the departments, either you can do this multiple times, or you can add a new node in your database which has the doctors' information sorted by `depid`, this will get the work done, I think.

Comment: thanks so much i duplicate the solution and success i know it slowly but it's work fine

Comment: your answer is correct but not the perfect so aim waiting for perfect answer  if no so i will accept your answer

Comment: @m.senan the only approach I could think of (when I REALLY sat, thinking about this) for doing this efficiently without duplicating the code is making some supportive changes in the database. I'm almost sure that this would be the only effective thing you can do to implement your wish.

Comment: @m.senan no worries, glad to help :) Cheers!